# Hibernate too much queries from one Bean

Tags: java, hibernate, jsf-2

I just managed to make my managed bean a requestscoped to be able to reload data after submitting and not having to reload the whole application (restart) to see new data being used on the app, but when I even click on any input, I see another hibernate query selecting all the form inputs

The form :

```
    <h:form id="formConfig">
   <h:panelGroup rendered="#{platformMB.firstedit == '0'}" >
           <p:messages id="messages" showSummary="false" showDetail="true" autoUpdate="true" closable="true" />
            <p:dataTable id="platform" var="platform" value="#{platformMB.platformData}" style="width: 90%" editable="true">  
                <p:ajax event="rowEdit" listener="#{platformMB.onEdit}" update=":formConfig:messages"/>
                <p:ajax event="rowEditCancel" listener="#{platformMB.onCancel}" update=":formConfig:messages"/>             

                <p:column headerText="Titre">
                    <f:facet name="Config">
                        <h:outputText value="TitreSite"/>
                    </f:facet>
                    <p:cellEditor>
                          <f:facet name="output">
                            <h:outputText value="#{platform.titresite}"/>
                        </f:facet>
                        <f:facet name="input">
                               <p:inputText  value="#{platform.titresite}" label="Titre">
                               <f:validateLength minimum="10" maximum="100"/>
                               </p:inputText>
                        </f:facet>             
                    </p:cellEditor>
                </p:column>
                <p:column headerText="Description">
                    <f:facet name="Config">
                        <h:outputText value="Description"/>
                    </f:facet>
                    <p:cellEditor>
                          <f:facet name="output">
                            <h:outputText value="#{platform.description}"/>
                        </f:facet>
                        <f:facet name="input">
                               <p:inputText value="#{platform.description}" label="Description">
                                <f:validateLength minimum="0" maximum="1000"/>
                               </p:inputText>
                        </f:facet>             
                    </p:cellEditor>
                </p:column>
                 <p:column headerText="Url">
                    <f:facet name="Config">
                        <h:outputText value="Url"/>
                    </f:facet>
                    <p:cellEditor>
                          <f:facet name="output">
                            <h:outputText value="#{platform.url}"/>
                        </f:facet>
                        <f:facet name="input">
                               <p:inputText value="#{platform.url}" label="Url">
                                 <f:validateLength minimum="0" maximum="45"/>
                               </p:inputText>
                        </f:facet>             
                    </p:cellEditor>
                </p:column>                
                                 <p:column headerText="Adresse">
                    <f:facet name="Config">
                        <h:outputText value="Adresse"/>
                    </f:facet>
                    <p:cellEditor>
                          <f:facet name="output">
                            <h:outputText value="#{platform.adress}"/>
                        </f:facet>
                        <f:facet name="input">
                               <p:inputText value="#{platform.adress}" label="Adresse">
                               <f:validateLength minimum="20" maximum="500"/>
                               </p:inputText>
                        </f:facet>             
                    </p:cellEditor>
                </p:column>     
                                 <p:column headerText="Phone">
                    <f:facet name="Config">
                        <h:outputText value="Phone"/>
                    </f:facet>
                    <p:cellEditor>
                          <f:facet name="output">
                            <h:outputText value="#{platform.phone}"/>
                        </f:facet>
                        <f:facet name="input">
                               <p:inputText value="#{platform.phone}" label="Télephone">
                               <f:validateLength minimum="8" maximum="11"/>
                               </p:inputText>
                        </f:facet>             
                    </p:cellEditor>
                </p:column>           
                                 <p:column headerText="E-mail Principal">
                    <f:facet name="Config">
                        <h:outputText value="E-mail Principal"/>
                    </f:facet>
                    <p:cellEditor>
                          <f:facet name="output">
                            <h:outputText value="#{platform.primarymail}"/>
                        </f:facet>
                        <f:facet name="input">
                               <p:inputText validatorMessage="E-mail : l'adresse e-mail saisie est incorrecte" value="#{platform.primarymail}" label="E-mail">
                               <f:validateRegex pattern="^[_A-Za-z0-9-\+]+(\.[_A-Za-z0-9-]+)*@[A-Za-z0-9-]+(\.[A-Za-z0-9]+)*(\.[A-Za-z]{2,})$" />
                               </p:inputText>
                        </f:facet>             
                    </p:cellEditor>
                </p:column>     
                <p:column style="width:20%">
                <f:facet name="Config">Mise à jour</f:facet>
                <p:rowEditor/>
            </p:column>       

            </p:dataTable>


        </h:panelGroup>
        <h:panelGroup rendered="#{platformMB.firstedit == '1'}">

        <table>
            <tr>
                <td><h:outputLabel for="titresite" value="Titre de l'institution : "/></td>
                <td><p:inputText id="titresite" value="#{platformMB.titresite}">
                    <f:validateLength minimum="10" maximum="100"/>
                    <p:ajax event="blur" update="titresiteMsg"/>
                </p:inputText>
                    <p:message id="titresiteMsg" for="titresite" display="icon"/>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><h:outputLabel for="description" value="Description de l'institution : "/></td>
                <td><p:inputText id="description" value="#{platformMB.description}">
                    <f:validateLength minimum="0" maximum="1000"/>
                    <p:ajax event="blur" update="descriptionMsg"/>
                </p:inputText>
                    <p:message id="descriptionMsg" for="description" display="icon"/>
                </td>
            </tr>
                        <tr>
                <td><h:outputLabel for="url" value="Adresse du site Web d'accueil : "/></td>
                <td><p:inputText id="url" value="#{platformMB.url}">
                    <f:validateLength minimum="0" maximum="45"/>
                    <p:ajax event="blur" update="urlMsg"/>
                </p:inputText>
                    <p:message id="urlMsg" for="url" display="icon"/>
                </td>
            </tr>
                              <tr>
                <td><h:outputLabel for="adress" value="Adresse de l'institution : "/></td>
                <td><p:inputText id="adress" value="#{platformMB.adress}">
                    <f:validateLength minimum="20" maximum="500"/>
                    <p:ajax event="blur" update="adressMsg"/>
                </p:inputText>
                    <p:message id="adressMsg" for="adress" display="icon"/>
                </td>
            </tr>
                                          <tr>
                <td><h:outputLabel for="phone" value="Téléphone de l'institution : "/></td>
                <td><p:inputText id="phone" value="#{platformMB.phone}">
                    <f:validateLength minimum="8" maximum="11"/>
                    <f:converter converterId="javax.faces.Integer"/>
                    <p:ajax event="blur" update="phoneMsg"/>
                </p:inputText>
                    <p:message id="phoneMsg" for="phone" display="icon"/>
                </td>
            </tr>
                                                      <tr>
                <td><h:outputLabel for="primarymail" value="E-mail principal de l'institution : "/></td>
                <td><p:inputText id="primarymail" value="#{platformMB.primarymail}">
                    <f:validateRegex pattern="^[_A-Za-z0-9-\+]+(\.[_A-Za-z0-9-]+)*@[A-Za-z0-9-]+(\.[A-Za-z0-9]+)*(\.[A-Za-z]{2,})$" />
                    <p:ajax event="blur" update="primarymailMsg"/>
                </p:inputText>
                    <p:message id="primarymailMsg" for="primarymail" display="icon"/>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><p:commandButton id="addPlatform" value="Sauvegarder" action="#{platformMB.addPlatform}" ajax="false"/></td>
                <td><p:commandButton id="reset" value="Reset" action="#{platformMB.reset}" ajax="false"/></td>
            </tr>
        </table>

            </h:panelGroup>
        </h:form>
```

Opening the page and clicking on the six inputs makes the console :

```
Hibernate: select platform0_.ID as ID0_, platform0_.ADRESS as ADRESS0_, platform0_.DESCRIPTION as DESCRIPT3_0_, platform0_.PHONE as PHONE0_, platform0_.PRIMARYMAIL as PRIMARYM5_0_, platform0_.TITRESITE as TITRESITE0_, platform0_.URL as URL0_ from PLATFORM platform0_
Hibernate: select platform0_.ID as ID0_, platform0_.ADRESS as ADRESS0_, platform0_.DESCRIPTION as DESCRIPT3_0_, platform0_.PHONE as PHONE0_, platform0_.PRIMARYMAIL as PRIMARYM5_0_, platform0_.TITRESITE as TITRESITE0_, platform0_.URL as URL0_ from PLATFORM platform0_
Hibernate: select platform0_.ID as ID0_, platform0_.ADRESS as ADRESS0_, platform0_.DESCRIPTION as DESCRIPT3_0_, platform0_.PHONE as PHONE0_, platform0_.PRIMARYMAIL as PRIMARYM5_0_, platform0_.TITRESITE as TITRESITE0_, platform0_.URL as URL0_ from PLATFORM platform0_
Hibernate: select platform0_.ID as ID0_, platform0_.ADRESS as ADRESS0_, platform0_.DESCRIPTION as DESCRIPT3_0_, platform0_.PHONE as PHONE0_, platform0_.PRIMARYMAIL as PRIMARYM5_0_, platform0_.TITRESITE as TITRESITE0_, platform0_.URL as URL0_ from PLATFORM platform0_
Hibernate: select platform0_.ID as ID0_, platform0_.ADRESS as ADRESS0_, platform0_.DESCRIPTION as DESCRIPT3_0_, platform0_.PHONE as PHONE0_, platform0_.PRIMARYMAIL as PRIMARYM5_0_, platform0_.TITRESITE as TITRESITE0_, platform0_.URL as URL0_ from PLATFORM platform0_
Hibernate: select platform0_.ID as ID0_, platform0_.ADRESS as ADRESS0_, platform0_.DESCRIPTION as DESCRIPT3_0_, platform0_.PHONE as PHONE0_, platform0_.PRIMARYMAIL as PRIMARYM5_0_, platform0_.TITRESITE as TITRESITE0_, platform0_.URL as URL0_ from PLATFORM platform0_
Hibernate: select platform0_.ID as ID0_, platform0_.ADRESS as ADRESS0_, platform0_.DESCRIPTION as DESCRIPT3_0_, platform0_.PHONE as PHONE0_, platform0_.PRIMARYMAIL as PRIMARYM5_0_, platform0_.TITRESITE as TITRESITE0_, platform0_.URL as URL0_ from PLATFORM platform0_
```

Comment: What exactly is the method `platformMB.onEdit` doing? I bet there is an entity you are loading that is not fully fetched.

Comment: Well, it's a lost bet .. 
 public void onEdit(RowEditEvent event) {
  try {
  FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage(null, new FacesMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_INFO, "Succès : ", "Modification Sauvegardée"));
        updatePlatform((Platform)event.getObject());
  }
  catch (Exception e){
   FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage(null, new FacesMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_INFO, "Erreur : ", "Veuillez vous reconnecter"));
  }
    }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was caused by the RequestScoped, and an Ajax is also considered as a Request, it contacts the Bean everytime a blur happens as the validator is invoked on blur, making the bean call again the select.

Changing this to ViewScoped is the solution.